# Why was Wubi Removed from 13.04+

Tags: wubi

Since 13.04, there is no Wubi, why was Wubi removed from the installation phase?

Comment: Related (and maybe should be considered a duplicate, since it provides up-to-date information on the same topic): [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](http://askubuntu.com/q/449486/22949) (also applies, for the most part, to releases between 13.04 and 14.04, and even explains the 13.04 situation)