# 13.10 installing issues/ metalink

Tags: 13.10

i tried to install 13.10 (32-bit)through wubi.exe and got an error message

```
Cannot download the meta link and ISO
```

Then the installation process stopped. i would like to know the  reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi is no longer supported for Ubuntu 13.4 and above, see the answer on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360616/why-was-wubi-removed-from-13-04).
Is there a reason that you don't want to use a normal installation? you could install 12.04 via wubi but there are some bugs and problems in wubi so I would strongly advice to do a [normal installation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest) and click the install along windows option.