# Not able to install Ubuntu 12.04 using wubi

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, wubi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 in my windows machine using Wubi. It's not the first time I am trying to install using Wubi, I have done that before but I am facing some issues this time...

I have downloaded ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso(in zip) from the Ubuntu's website.

[image]
After extracting all the files when I am trying to run wubi.. it's giving an error :

[image: without internet connection]

With my internet connection on, wubi downloads a file..

[image]

But at the end of downloading, this gives "Permission Denied" error.

I also searched a lot, and tried different ways like putting the latest wubi in the folder. But nothing worked for me.. Any suggestion ??

A question here, I have already downloaded iso zip but wubi still searching for another disc image file.Doesn't it come in the iso zip files??

Comment: One of your screen shots shows an efi partition. Is this a new pre-installed Windows 8 system? If so it uses gpt partitioning and wubi does not work on gpt partitioned drives. http://askubuntu.com/questions/360616/why-was-wubi-removed-from-13-04

Comment: No, it's not... It's Windows Vista.And that EFI folder comes after extracting the iso zip file...

Comment: Wubi also changed not to install from DVD, but just from inside Windows. Not sure of details, but you download a executeable and run that to download and install wubi. But not from live installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donwload [Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso) 32bit iso image, and after that download [wubi installer](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/wubi.exe), place both files in the same folder on your desktop or somewhere else and run wubi.exe with your Internet connection down. Don't forget that you cannot allocate more than 30GB for Ubuntu installation when using wubi installer. It should work fine. You can use wubi installer in the same manner to install inside windows Xubuntu 12.04.4 and also Lubuntu 12.04.4 (better choice for older machines than Ubuntu 12.04.4 which runs in a Gnome session and can create lots of issues after first system upgrade and also after you update your video driver).