# Problem Installing Ubuntu Using Windows Installer

Tags: wubi

I am trying to install Ubuntu using the Windows installer (my first time trying to use Linux!), and when I try to download the installer, I get the screen asking for donations, but can't go any further. There is a "pay with paypal" button, and no way to continue. Any help appreciated! I am using XP.

Comment: i paid the fee/donation, and I still can't get the installer to work. ON hour #3 now. It's on my computer, on an USB stick, and I can't get Windows XP to reboot to it.

Comment: Go to this page [http://askubuntu.com/questions/445764/not-able-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-using-wubi/445909#445909] and follow instructions from my post. Download the 2 files you need to install Ubuntu inside Windows and place them in the same folder. Then you can install Ubuntu with wubi installer.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred option is to first try the system using a live boot USB.  In other words it boots from the USB and runs a complete system (though slower than an actual install) without making any changes to the computer at all.  Don't pay unless you really want to and only after you are sure everything is working, just click the "Not now take me to the download" link.  Because I use Ubuntu all the time on several computers I typically donate during the update cycle but it certainly isn't necessary.

1. Download the ISO.
2. Get a USB boot creation tool like [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).
3. Create the bootable USB.
4. Use whatever function keys allow you to access the boot menu (Dell uses F12) to boot from the USB.
5. On boot select "Try Ubuntu" rather than install.
6. After playing around if you like it there is an install app on the desktop or you can reboot using the same procedure and select install instead of try.
7. If you install Ubuntu as a dual boot (in case you need to go back to Windows to get something) you will have access to the old Windows partition from inside Ubuntu.